# Matching forward slash `/` within Perl (Escaping forward slash)

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match a forward slash `/` in a Perl find or replace query.

Comment: What's wrong with using another delimiters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\` before it in order to escape it.